# SharePoint 2010 OOB Presence support for logged in users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am wanting to have presence shown on my site for the users logged into SharePoint.
I have a SP2010 install and site collection.  Within central admin, I have "Person Name Actions and Presence Settings" enabled for the web application I am using.  What additional steps do I need to do to enable presence display on my site?  Is Office Communicator (Lync 2010) required for presence support OOB?

If I want presence shown based on who is logged in to AD what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence setting is for someone logged onto Lync and not sharepoint. There is no out of the box way to see who is online on sharepoint.

However, if someone is logged onto Lync, you will see the presence associated with it.